# In csv file how to find maximum value (5 nos.) and their corresponding column uisng python

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

I have a .csv file having numeric(float) data. Want to find top 5 maximum values and their corresponding column

Comment: This is not a site for finding people to write code for you.  This site is about asking specific questions about programming.  Take a shot at this problem yourself.  Get to a point where after learning Python and studying how to use a CSV reader Python module, you are still stuck.  Then put the code you're having trouble with in your question, and someone here may be able to help you to get it to work.  You might want to read [Can someone help me?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: Please share the code and the csv data.